# size of Xor of BigIntegers

Tags: java, size, byte, biginteger, xor

My programm makes two random BigInteger with a bitLength of 255. Then it makes a xor of those two BigInteger.

Problem is: since the magnitude of Big Integers is minimal, if the firsts bits are 0 the size of this xor can be smaller than 255. And i need it to be 32 bytes, so between 248 and 256 bits.

Here is my code :

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SecureRandom random;
        BigInteger randomBigInteger1;
        byte[] randomBytes;
        do {
            random = new SecureRandom();
            randomBytes = new byte[32];
            random.nextBytes(randomBytes);
            randomBigInteger1 = new BigInteger(randomBytes);
        }while(randomBigInteger1.bitLength() < 255);

        BigInteger randomBigInteger2;
        do {
            random = new SecureRandom();
            randomBytes = new byte[32];
            random.nextBytes(randomBytes);
            randomBigInteger2 = new BigInteger(randomBytes);
        }while(randomBigInteger2.bitLength() < 255);

        BigInteger finalXor = randomBigInteger1.xor(randomBigInteger2);
        System.out.println(finalXor.bitLength());

        byte[] key = finalXor.toByteArray();
        System.out.println(key.length);
    }

}
```

Question is: how to make sure that key will always be 32 bytes, even when the finalXor is less than 248bits? (i guess i can make a padding with bits 0 but i don't know how.)

Example: let's sya my BigIntegers are:

1111011010101101.............11011100011

1111011001100111.............01110011010

Then the finalXor will be:

0000000011001010.............10101111001

The 8 highers bits are all null, so the finalXor length is only 255-8 = 247 bits long. When i make the byte[] key, it will then be 31bytes and not 32. 
I need it to be 32 bytes. And still be the good xor.

That's why i said i think i should make a padding where all "missing higher bits" are 0, but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Depends what you want to do if it isn't - you can check the number of bits in the number with `bitLength` - see [What is the difference between `bitCount()` and `bitLength()` of a `BigInteger`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407351/what-is-the-difference-between-bitcount-and-bitlength-of-a-biginteger)

Comment: I'm already using bitLength and not bitCount. What happens is: sometimes, the highers bits of both BigIntegers are the same, and so when you wor them the higher bits are 0, which makes my finalXor smaller than 255bits. As said, i don't really care...until it's still bigger than 248bits. But it can happens that it's not. In this case, i want to make sure that the byte array i make with this BigInteger will still be 32 bytes long, and still be the xor of the two other integers.

Comment: Then you need to pad it yourself with zero bytes. BigInteger will always use the minimum number of bytes to represent a number.

Comment: ok, but how? I've tried key[32] = 0 but it doesn't make sense since key[32] is a byte, not a bit. And it doesn't work.

Comment: key[32] can't exist. key can have 32 bytes at most (but it can be smaller). The highest index you can use is key.length - 1, and never 32.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis yeah you're right. I meant the 32th byte, so key[31]. I've also tried key[31] = new Byte(0); or things like that. But it seems that, to set a byte, there's no other solution than using Byte.parseByte()  (or at least i didn't found any other)

Comment: What about `key[31] = 0;` instead of `= new Byte(0);`? The latter does not do what you think it does. No need for `parseByte()`.

Answer (score 0):

Padding with 0 is an option, and i found a way to do it:

```
if(key.length != 32) {
    byte[] finalKey= new byte[32];
    byte a = Byte.parseByte("00000000", 2);
    for(int i =0; i<key.length; i++) 
        finalKey[i] = key[i];
    for (int i = key.length ; i<32 ; i++)
        finalKey[i] = a;
    key = finalKey;
}
```

It requires a loop and another byte array, because for some reason key[31] throw an ArrayOutOfBound exception, but it works...if anyone can improve it, feel free to do so.

EDIT: better solution by OldCurmudgeon :

```
key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 32);
```

It will automatically fill the higher bits with 0.

Comment: You can use `Arrays.copyOf(byte[] original, int newLength)` and specify the newLength as `32`.

Answer (score 0):

ISTM that **avoiding** BigInteger and *xoring* the byte arrays directly could solve several of your problems at once. There is padding where necessary, and you always get a 32 byte array.

If you make sure that the top bytes (at index 0 because of big-endiannes) are not the same, you will always have a 248-255 bit value.

If little-endiannes is required, then the bytes at index 31 must not be 0 and be different. I assumed big-endian, because that is what a BigInteger returns too, in your original code.

```
public class test 
{    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

        // make "left" operand
        byte[] randomBytesLeft = new bytes[32];
        random.nextBytes(randomBytesLeft);

        // make "right" operand
        byte[] randomBytesRight = new byte[32];
        do 
        {
            random.nextBytes(randomBytesRight);
        } while (randomBytesRight[0] == randomBytesLeft[0]); // or [31] for little-endian

        // "xor" both operands
        byte[] key = new byte[32];
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            key[i] = randomBytesLeft[i] ^ randomBytesRight[i];
        }

        // if you really need a BigInteger:
        // BigInteger finalXor = new BigInteger(key);

        System.out.println(key.length);
    }
}
```

FWIW, it seems to me that you could **omit the *xoring* altogether**, and just do:

```
        byte[] key = new byte[32];
        do
        {
            random.nextBytes(key);
        } while (key[0] == 0); // or key[31] for little-endian
```

That would probably be just as good and much simpler.

Comment: That could. However, my code up here is just for the test. in practice, the two BigInteger come from another function from BC library. It returns BigInteger so i have to use it. Plus, each is calculated on a different client machine and send to the server, which then make a xor. So this won't solve my problem at all.

Comment: @Ablia: you could have mentioned those details in the question. In that case, I would not have taken the time to write my answer.