# Number of bits allocated to 0 is 0 in java- Why?

Tags: java

While learning `BigInteger.valueOf(0L).bitLength()` and `BigInteger.valueOf(0L).bitCount()` I found it is `returning 0`

However, the if consider `0` as a number then it should also needs `one bit`.

From my understanding I expect `1` as `return` value for both methods instead of `0`.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int bitLength = BigInteger.valueOf(0L).bitLength();
        int bitCount = BigInteger.valueOf(0L).bitCount();
        System.out.println("bitLength=" + bitLength);
        System.out.println("bitCount=" + bitCount);
    }
 }
```

Please help me understand why It is behaving like this ?

Comment: It has to do with 2's compliment, from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html): `Returns the number of bits in the two's complement representation of this BigInteger that differ from its sign bit.`. The sign bit of 0 is 0, so no bits are present which differ, hence the bit count is zero.

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44407351/1043824

Comment: Did you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of the two methods? If so, which part of the documentation contradicts the values you see?

Comment: By the way neither of these functions is directly related to how many bits are allocated to store the value. They just say something about the value itself in an abstract sense.

Comment: @Andreas-- Yes I did and I know it is not written by GOD so there must be a reason behind that and that is why I am asking why it is so ????Any specific reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **int bitCount()**
>
> Returns the number of bits in the two's complement representation of this BigInteger that differ from its sign bit.

For your `BigInteger.valueOf(0L)` example, the sign bit is 0, and there are no 1 bits, hence 0 is returned (since there are no bits that differ from the sign bit).

> **int  bitLength()**
>
> Returns the number of bits in the minimal two's-complement representation of this BigInteger, excluding a sign bit.

For your `BigInteger.valueOf(0L)` example, the minimal two's-complement representation of this `BigInteger` would include just the sign bit `0`, so if you exclude the sign bit from the count, as the Javadoc states, you get 0.

It is interesting to note that for the same reasons `BigInteger.valueOf(-1L)` would also return 0 for both of these methods. Here the sign bit is `1`, and after excluding it there are no other bits.

Answer (score 0):

The high-level explanation is that if you have a storage system with a variable number of data bits plus a count, then the count provides some information on the value of the number, so the number of data bits required is less than a system without a count (or with a fixed count).

For normal integer types the "count" is provided by the type information and it is a fixed value. So there is an assumption, for example, that a short is 16 bits, an int is 32 bits, etc. Because of the few possibiities that a size can be (it is not fully variable) the number of bits used even for a zero value is also fixed at that number.

For `BigInteger`, the bit count is variable and there are various counts you can look at in the source code; some seem redundant, but the unavoidable one is the length of the data array:

```
final int[] mag;
```

Setting this array to length zero can represent a zero value, but since you still have the array count, it isn't really using zero bytes.

The `bitCount` and `bitLength` values have somewhat arbitrary definitions that don't really relate to the memory utilisation of the class but do have some functional use.

An explanation of the difference between these two methods is given in another question: [What is the difference between `bitCount()` and `bitLength()` of a `BigInteger`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407351/what-is-the-difference-between-bitcount-and-bitlength-of-a-biginteger).

Answer (score 0):

Good reference about difference in both calls - [Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407351/what-is-the-difference-between-bitcount-and-bitlength-of-a-biginteger) 
[Official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitLength--)

0 is neither positive nor negative.

```
BigInteger h = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
System.out.println("h="+ h 
    + "[binary=" + h.toString(2) + "]"
    + "[bit count="+ h.bitCount()+ "]" 
    + "[bit length=" + h.bitLength() + "]");
h = h.negate();
System.out.println("h="+ h 
    + "[binary=" + h.toString(2) + "]"
    + "[bit count="+ h.bitCount()+ "]" 
    + "[bit length=" + h.bitLength() + "]");
//Output
//h=0[binary=0][bit count=0][bit length=0]
//h=0[binary=0][bit count=0][bit length=0]
```

Few samples for positive and negative numbers - 
1[binary=1][bit count=1][bit length=1]
-1[binary=-1][bit count=0][bit length=0]
2[binary=10][bit count=1][bit length=2]
-2[binary=-10][bit count=1][bit length=1]
3[binary=11][bit count=2][bit length=2]
-3[binary=-11][bit count=1][bit length=2]
8[binary=1000][bit count=1][bit length=4]
-8[binary=-1000][bit count=3][bit length=3]
10[binary=1010][bit count=2][bit length=4]
-10[binary=-1010][bit count=2][bit length=4]
13[binary=1101][bit count=3][bit length=4]
-13[binary=-1101][bit count=2][bit length=4]
50[binary=110010][bit count=3][bit length=6]
-50[binary=-110010][bit count=3][bit length=6]